# Downloading an image from sephora using python

Tags: python, get, web-application-firewall

I am trying to download images from Sephora website using python. The server is blocking the download request.

I have tried many libraries like wget, urllib, Requests Library. https://www.sephora.com/productimages/sku/s2586261-main-zoom.jpg, this is the sample link.

Here is one of the sample codes I have tried.

```
import urllib.request

opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

filename = 'test.jpg'
image_url = "https://www.sephora.com/productimages/sku/s2586261-main-zoom.jpg"

urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, filename)
```

Any suggestions on different methods to download an image from the sample link.

Comment: did you get any error message from server? You should show it in question (not in comments). Maybe it needs some extra header. Eventually you will need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser.

Comment: I can download only when I use module `requests` with `User-Agent` from my browser. But `requests` doesn't work with your `User-Agent`, And it doesn't work when I use `urllib` with my `User-Agent`. Maybe server has very complex system to detect users. I visited `sephora.com` in my browser many times before and maybe server remembers my browser.

Comment: I can download using `wget` or `curl` only when I use `User-Agent` from my browser. And when I try to use `curl` without `User-Agent` then I get HTML with message `"You don't have permission to access https://www.sephora.com/productimages/sku/s2586261-main-zoom.jpg"`